# Efficient computation of a bilinear norm over sparse vectors in Python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

Given two column vectors x, y : scipy.sparse.csc_matrix, where len(x) == len(y) == N and max(x.nnz, y.nnz) == M, and a symmetric N × N matrix A : scipy.sparse.csc_matrix, where for all columns j, A[j].nnz = C, I need to compute x.T * A * y = ∑∑ᵢ,ⱼ x[i] * a[j][i] * y[j] efficiently in at most M * max(M, C) steps, which can be achieved as follows:

- in the outer loop, we iterate over the y.nnz columns j of A,
- in the inner loop, we iterate over either:

  - the x.nnz rows i of A, if x.nnz < C, or
  - the C rows i of A, otherwise.

My question is whether this can be achieved using high-level Python and existing libraries (and if so, then how), or whether this requires custom C / C++ code.

---

The following naive Python code using the scipy library:

```py
(x.T).dot(A).dot(y)[0, 0]
```

computes separately:

- x.T * A using up to x.nnz * N steps, and
- ∑ⱼ (x.T * A)[j] * y[j] using up to M steps.

This takes O(M * N) steps in total, which is a major slow-down for large N.

Comment: Correct, I missed the sparse part. I don't think there is something so high level for sparse matrices. The `dot` methods you use though are sparse aware, though, as you say- have some redundancy.

Comment: `sparse` matrix multiplication efficiently takes advantage of the sparsity of its inputs (but is slower than numpy dot for non-sparse matrices).  So calculation time depends more on the number of nonzero terms than the dimensions.

Comment: I am aware of that. The number of nonzero elements in x, y, and A is well below 0.01 percent and A would take N² × 4B of space when stored dense (which amounts to about 1TiB of RAM in my case).

Comment: Well then lets first filter out those columns of `A`.  But sparse does column selection with a matrix multiplication (by an extractor matrix).

Comment: In this case, scipy can't do column selection. It first performs the x.T * A matrix product, which alone will take O(M * N) steps without taking into account that an inner product with y will follow.

Comment: But you got me thinking. Slicing x, A, and y into smaller dense matrices might be feasible.